# Can items in the toybox be unlocked without fighting?

Tags: disney-infinity-2.0

My daughter likes to play with the Disney Infinity toybox but most of the items are locked and can't be used.  As far as I can tell you can only unlock items by fighting bad guys and unlocking sparks.

My daughter really likes creating things but does not like fighting, racing, etc.  Is it possible to get toybox items without fighting or purchasing sparks with real money?

We are playing Disney Infinity on the PC and have not bought any characters yet.  Thanks.

Comment: If you really wanted to, you could do the fighting/racing/game-types-that-she-does-not-like-that-reward-items yourself. This could potentially unlock a decent amount of items, but only if you felt like playing the game.

Answer (score 1):

If you turn into a car character, you get sparks for doing tricks (although this is not very effective).
I played on Xbox, so this might not work though.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a capsule creator toy which when turned on will randomly add capsules around the toy box area for you to find. Collecting the blue capsules will give you some sparks.

The rate at which you get sparks may not be that fast though.

Answer (score -3):

you can buy certain discs and they unlock toys

Comment: This answer is very vague. Please give more details, because in its current state, the answer doesn't help.